# .htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work without R flag

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

But this rule only works when I add a R=301 flag... The problem is that the url is rewritten in the address bar of the browser.
How can I redirect and keep the url that the user typed in the address bar ?

Comment: Well, what happens when you do not specify the R flag ?

Comment: And: where did you specify that rule ? In the server configuration or on a per-directory level ?

Comment: @arkascha there is no redirect without R flag and an other (existing) page is displayed

Comment: The rule is specified in the .htaccess file of my drupal site

Comment: Of yourse there is no redirect in the browser without "R" flag. Because you don't ask for a redirect without. Rewriting rules without "R" flag do not send a redirect. They rewrite server internally, that is what they are meant to do. You should read the documentation !

Answer (score 0):

A 301 is sent back to the browser, which sends a new request to the redirected page. That is why the browser is redirected.

Use the **Local redirect**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the user url, you should use the "ProxyRequest" in your vhost.conf.
[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).